# Change URL only for empty shopping cart

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

How can I change the URL for shopping cart when is empty?

Right now is `/checkout/cart/` and when there are no items in the shopping cart I would like to have `/checkout/cart/empty/`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Override the CartController and create a new Action (public function emptyAction())
2) Check in indexAction if the cart is empty to place a redirect to cart/empty
3) done!

HTH!

Comment: Can you please be more specific. I am a beginner when it comes to this. Thank you!